# Changing the Title of the Back Button in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

This may be a silly question, but how would I go about changing the 'back' button of the navigation controller to simply say 'Back' every time I push to a different ViewController?

For example, if I'm going from the Master to the Detail then it will have: "< Master" as the back button text. Can I change it easily to "< Back" without messing around too much? (It's just I have quite a few segues going and if I have to replace the button manually I'm probably going to screw up something else...)

All help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `backBarButtonItem` to the current navigation item before pushing another. Navigation items are pushed when view controllers are pushed.

So something like this:

```
self.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:NULL];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next];
```

The target and action of the bar button item are not required, as only the title is used.

You can set `backBarButtonItem` once in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for explaining. I understand what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

It automatically grabs the title of the previous view controller as long as the title is short enough to fit into the button. To override this behavior, you can provide your own UIBarButtonItem for the `backBarButtonItem` property. (Just create a basic push button and it should work IIRC.)